# Gradle doesn't import jsoup into jar file

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to pack my whole application into one .jar file using gradle. But it seems to not working.

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
 group 'imgscrapper'
 version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'


 sourceCompatibility = 1.5

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
 jar {
     manifest {
         sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['Main/src']
         attributes 'Main-Class': 'imgscrapper.Main'

     }
 }
 dependencies {
     testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
     compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
     compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'
 }
```

and catalog tree:

```
 .
 ├── production
 │   └── Main
 │       ├── com
 │       │   └── intellij
 │       │       └── uiDesigner
 │       │           └── core
 │       │               ├── AbstractLayout.class
 │       │               ├── DimensionInfo.class
 │       │               ├── GridConstraints.class
 │       │               ├── GridLayoutManager.class
 │       │               ├── HorizontalInfo.class
 │       │               ├── LayoutState.class
 │       │               ├── Spacer.class
 │       │               ├── SupportCode.class
 │       │               ├── SupportCode$TextWithMnemonic.class
 │       │               ├── Util.class
 │       │               └── VerticalInfo.class
 │       └── imgscrapper
 │           ├── Frame$1.class
 │           ├── Frame$2.class
 │           ├── Frame$3.class
 │           ├── Frame$4.class
 │           ├── Frame$5.class
 │           ├── Frame.class
 │           ├── GetImages.class
 │           └── Main.class
 └── test
     └── Main
         └── com
             └── intellij
                 └── uiDesigner
                     └── core
                         ├── AbstractLayout.class
                         ├── DimensionInfo.class
                         ├── GridConstraints.class
                         ├── GridLayoutManager.class
                         ├── HorizontalInfo.class
                         ├── LayoutState.class
                         ├── Spacer.class
                         ├── SupportCode.class
                         ├── SupportCode$TextWithMnemonic.class
                         ├── Util.class
                         └── VerticalInfo.class
```

As far I know gradle should import jsoup into package on his own however when I'm trying to run my jar file I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/nodes/Document
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not how it works. Dependencies will not be added to the jar file being built out-of-the box.

To fix it you need to either build a fat-jar (with [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin) or use [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin (delivered by gradle with the distribution).